# Add Value to Variable in Lua?

Tags: lua

In most languages, I can easily do some mathematical function (add, subtract, etc...) to a variable's current value in a short form like `foo +=1`. Is there something similar in Lua?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No, there is no shortcut to `foo = foo + 1`.

Comment: @Eli Lua is a minimalistic language by design. The `+=` & C. operators would add almost nothing to the ease of use and readability of Lua and would have problems in interacting with other features (think for a moment of multiple assigments) cleanly.